# Using DbContext - Entity Framework 4.1 How do you set default values for entities

Tags: asp.net, orm, frameworks, entity

Just wondering How I can set default values for entities (Date Time values)?

Can you create a partial class from the generated classes and set values there

or is it better to override the SaveChanges method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those "it depends" questions. :)

I typically do this in the SaveChanges override. If you are not adverse to putting this logic into the data layer, then it's what I recommend.

Another strategy I use with POCOs when I have something like a DateCreated field in every class, is to to use an interface or base class that exposes the property so you don't have to look for each type that might have the date property in it when you do the mod in the SaveChanges override.

WRT "can you create a partial class?": yes, that works, too. If you are using the EDMX & code generation (I suspect this because you mention a partial class) then you can add a constructor in the partial class that sets the default date in the appropriate property/ies.

HTH
Julie

Comment: The SaveChanges override sounds good - any examples showing this using DbContext?